# Mapnik: too many "LIMIT 0" queries

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-performance, mapnik

I have a xml project file with several layers, many of which divided in turn into 2 (low/high) or 3 (low/mid/high) layers, each one covering different zoom ranges. The whole number of layers (considering sub-divisions too) is 42. I use the python-mapnik binding with mapnik 3.0.12.
Well, if I give a look at PostgreSQL logs, every time I make a request for a single map image (a simple static image, not a series of tiles) at a given zoom level, that would normally require only 12 (out of 42) queries to be executed, I always see 42 times this:

"duration: xx.xxx ms statement: "

followed by the definition of the query itsefl, plus "LIMIT 0" at the end.
Then I can find 12 times this:

"duration: xx.xxx ms execute :"

which is about the 12 queries that were actually needed to be executed.
I suppose that the 42 queries with the trailing "LIMIT 0" are "check queries", performed to analyze which index would be the best one to use, etc...but I would like to know if there is a way to do this only for the queries that actually have to be executed at a time, not for all the queries (layers) in the project.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed similar behavior in my mapnik project file (I'm working with the Node.js bindings). I was able to reduce the number of queries to the database, by providing `extent` and `srid` parameters in the `Datasource` element:

```
<Datasource>
    <Parameter name="extent">-180 -90,180 90</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="srid">4326</Parameter>
</Datasource>
```

I believe mapnik executes two queries ahead of the query to retrieve the features to determine the SRID and the extent of the layer. By providing these ahead of time in the datasource, mapnik won't need to execute these queries.

Comment: I realized it was my fault: in my code I was calling repeatedly `mapnik.load_map(...)` method at each tile request rather than only once when starting the server.